Git Log between tags show commits from another tag
I am executing a command to get a commits between two tags:

 git log --merges '7.0.8'...'7.0.9' --oneline

Apart from commits that are between these two tags, I also receive some commit that was made before 7.0.8 tag and it`s laying between 7.0.7..7.0.8
Here are the commits that I get:

All the commits that under yellow line are laying after 7.0.8
It`s a bit confuse me, since I have task to retrieve commits between two tags.
Here screenshot of Git History from repository in GitLab:

I am expected to see the last commit in output "3f5c081", but for now it`s not clear to me why i see commits that should appear when executing command:

 git log --merges '7.0.7'...'7.0.8' --oneline

Maybe someone can explain this behavior?
I expect to see only commits made in range 7.0.8..7.0.9

as a general advice: add --graph to your git log  commands to understand how commits are related one to another. otherwise you are somehow "history blind"

Can you look at the combined history around your 3 tags ? git log --oneline --graph 7.0.9 7.0.8 7.0.7

also, a general SO rule: favor text over screen capture. Please copy/paste the text output of your terminal rather than a screenshot of your terminal.

There are merge commits in your history, a blind guess is: the list of commits brought in by these merges is not what you think it is, and fix-payment-service is not part of 7.0.8.

To have a clearer view of how commits are related one to another, add --graph to your git log commands:
# view the combined history for the tags you want to inspect:
git log --oneline --graph 7.0.9 7.0.8 7.0.7

When viewing partial history, like A..B or A...B,
--boundary may help:
git log --oneline --graph --boundary 7.0.8...7.0.9

(if you have many merge commits though, it may also make a confusing output; make up your own opinion by trying it)
